# Eclipse build failure when project folder has ampersand in pathname

Tags: eclipse, perforce

I have a C/C++ project which has some normal and some linked/virtual folders and it has been building just fine. Now that I've put it into perforce over VPN (the path of which I cannot modify), there is an ampersand in the path of the project that causes eclipse to fail when it gets to building the files in the linked folders (it appears eclipse builds an entire pathname for linked folder's files from the environment variables and passes that to the gnu compiler). I don't know if Perforce allows aliasing of workspaces (to get rid of the ampersand) but I can't find one. I've tried alt root but that doesn't seem to do anything useful. I've found that using the DOS command prompt subst F:

`C:\perforce\pathwithampersand` will allow the project to build in eclipse but now I loose the ability to utilize the Perforce plugin features. Although I can still manually check files in/out using the P4 client, it would be very useful if the ampersand problem was taken care of by eclipse. I've searched and searched but can't find anything about eclipse having a problem (or solution) with ampersand in the folder path. I'm using eclipse platform 4.2.1 and CDT 8.1.1 but cannot update to any later version(s) than those because they are part of a tool suite a vendor controls. Perforce plugin is 2013.1/server is 2009.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the P4 Client Connection->Edit Current Workspace
Expand the depot tree until you see your project. Right mouse click on it and choose Include Special. 
Click Files radio button and click the Save button.
That will cause a path name to be displayed next to your project under Client Expression. Click to the right of this path which will cause it to become editable. Cursor over to the part that includes the ampersand and delete it. Click the OK button.
P4 will then (eventually) ask if you want to update files to the new location (or something like that). Choose update and it will take some time to create the new folder and move the files there. It is unclear whether you need to log out of P4 for it to be completely enforced so the best solution is to do so (Connection->Log Off). It might leave the old directory so you can delete it at will and it will not appear the next time you start P4.
Some users found this sequence did not work this way so they had to click the "View workspace mapping as text" button  on the workspace edit dialog and delete the ampersand. Click apply.